Linking two cells to update one another
I would like to know if there is a way to "link" two cells in gsheets in order to update one another in function of the other.
Example: I have A1 and B1. If I write 5 in A1 I need it to write 5 in B1 automatically. But if I write 5 in B1 I need it also to write 5 in A1.
Is this something doable?
Thank you!
I looked up on google but I only see hyperlinks. However this is not what I am looking for.
